# OCaml splitting bytes vs characters

Tags: string, char, byte, ocaml

It seems I'm a little confused on the best way to handle this. At the moment I am using Jane Street's Core. Split has a signature that looks like

```
split : t -> on:char -> t list
```

Which is fine. However, I noticed that any string I type is a "Bytes" type. This creates a problem when I try to split because it expects a char. My question is, what is the best way to handle this? Right now I'm doing

```
String.split "My string is here" (String.get " " 0)
```

But this seems *very* hacky. I feel like there should be a better solution to this. Can anyone help me? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make a char using `'`s.

```
# "x";;
- : string = "x"
# 'x';;
- : char = x
# String.split "My string is here" ' ';;
- : string list = ["My"; "string"; "is"; "here"]
```

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to use regexp to solve your problem :

```
let () = 
  let l = Str.split (Str.regexp_string " ") "My string is here" in 
  List.iter (Printf.printf "%s\n") l
```

Comment: The regexp should be `"[ ]+"` if you want to avoid splitting empty elements on multiple spaces.